# How to make ImageView match width basing on fixed height?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a few images, which have to be scaled to common height, but differ by widths. How can I set them up inside `LinearLayout` to fixed height, such that their widths will be evaluated automatically to keep their aspect ratios?

I tried:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/clean"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/c4"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/c4"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/c4"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, effect is far from what I expected (images are too wide):

[image: Result]

Comment: Try use ``android:layout_width="0dp"`` and ``android:layout_weight="1"`` for all imageView

Comment: @DanhDC Doesn't work, bigger images are scaled down more than smaller ones...

Comment: So you want a square image view depending on the height of the image right ?

Comment: are you try set scaleType for it. e.g fitXY or fitCenter ?

Comment: @MalekHijazi I want all images to be scaled down to the same height, but keeping their aspect ratios, so widths will vary. Some images are wider than others.

Comment: @DanhDC Images are scaled correctly when I choose fitStart or fitEnd, but widths of their views are too big, making unnecessary gaps between images.

Comment: To me it seems your images have a white border. Try using a graphic editor software to get rid of white space left and right of your content

Answer (score 1):

Do like this, use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/clean"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
               android:layout_weight="0.25"
                 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/c4"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/c4"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/c4"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is not likely to work, first image is wider than the rest, it will be scaled down more than others...

Comment: use android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Answer (score 0):

Use width = "0" for all ImageViews with weight = "1" and set the **image as a background** inside the ImageView and not in the src.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The trick is to use both `android:scaleType="fitXY"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/clean"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/c4"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/c4"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/c4"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/c4"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/c4"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```